Setting a reference in Cox regression with splines and interaction
I run a Cox regression with a continuous variable age and a categorical variable sex. The model includes splines for the continuous variable and an interaction between both. I want to choose the reference point, i.e. the predictor combination having a relative risk of 1. Let's pick age of 80 and females as reference. At the moment I do the following:

I make predictions for the range of age for both sexes and save them in an object called pred.
I make predictions for 80yo females and save them in an object called ref.
I subtract ref from pred and save the results as pred_adjusted.
I compute the exponential function with exp(pred_adjusted) for the point estimate as well as the confidence interval.

In R that looks like this:
library(survival); library(splines)
# Fit model.
fit <- coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ sex * ns(age, 3), data= flchain)
# Predictor range and groups to predict for.
data_new <- expand.grid(age= seq(min(flchain$age), max(flchain$age), 1), sex= levels(flchain$sex))
# Predict.
pred <- predict(fit, data_new, se= TRUE)
# Calculate confidence interval.
pred <- pred$fit + outer(pred$se, c(0, -1.96, 1.96), '*')
# Predict reference.
ref <- predict(fit, newdata= data.frame(sex="F", age= 80))
# Substract and exp().
res <- exp(pred-ref)

The resulting data looks like this:

As expected, 80 yo females have a relative risk of 1. Nonetheless, I am not sure whether this is the way to set a reference. I read this but it uses survival::pspline which I do not want to use for some reasons. The approach with survival::pspline is quite different and gives slightly different results than splines::ns. Therefore, I can't infer from the source whether I am right. I also read this but it covers a much simpler situation. Thus, I am unsure whether what I do is correct. Any help appreciated!
The plot was made with this code:
plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(data_new, setNames(data.frame(exp(pred-ref)), nm= c("fit", "lower", "upper")))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x= age, y= fit)) +
  geom_line(aes(col= sex)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= lower, ymax= upper, fill= sex), alpha= .1) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10") +
  labs(y= "Relative risk (axis log10 scaled)") +
  geom_hline(yintercept= 1, lty= 2)


The vignette you cite says:

The approach is appropriate for any term, not just psplines.

In terms of simply setting a reference, you thus are OK. You were smart enough to use the predict() function instead of trying to use the individual regression coefficients to get the predictions yourself, thus avoiding a lot of potential problems.
You should, however, think more about how you specified the spline in the model. The ns(age, 3) function might not be as flexible a fit as you think.
First, the default with that function is to place boundary knots at the extremes of the data range. How many cases do you have with age close to 100? If you prefer a regression spline to the ps() penalized spline, consider using the rms package with its rcs() function instead. The default boundary knot placement is at intelligently specified quantiles within the data range (quantiles depending on the number of knots), and the choice of basis functions allows for a direct evaluation of the significance of the nonlinearity, which is more difficult with the basis functions used by ns().
Second, I think that what you have done (if I understand the ns() manual page correctly) is to have specified 3 degrees of freedom rather than 3 internal knots for the spline. It's not surprising that the ps() function, with its greater flexibility, gave you a different shape.
If you use rms functions for all your work, then you can get these types of plots very readily with its Predict() function and corresponding plot functions. There's a bit of an initial learning curve with that package, but it's worth it if you do much regression modeling.

So many great points! Thank you!
